# Execute each function only if the current iteration is not hovered element

Tags: jquery

I think hopefully my code will speak for its self.

When i hover over an element, i want to run an each function on all elements of the same class, but not the currently hovered element:

```
$(document).on({
mouseenter: function () {
    $('#%id% .imageStyle').each(function(){
        if($(this) != $(this)){ // obviously this line is incorrect
        // I only want to execute this if the current each iteration is not the element I am hovering over
            $.this.pixastic("desaturate");
        }
    });
    Pixastic.revert(this);
},

mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).pixastic("desaturate");
}
}, '#%id% .imageStyle');
```

Update, this new code does what I want now...

```
$(".%id%desaturate img").addClass("sprightly");


$(document).on({
mouseenter: function () {
    $('.sprightly').not(this).each(function(){
        if($(this).is("img")){
            $(this).trigger("mouseleave");
        }
    });
    Pixastic.revert(this);
},

mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).pixastic("desaturate");
}
}, '#%id% .imageStyle');
```

Comment: this can be done with 3 simple css rules, but alas only on webkit at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

There is no need to use the each function, since `.pixastic()` will apply for all elements matched by the selector. Try this out, i have not tested it

```
$("#container").on({
mouseenter: function () {
    $('#container .imageStyle').not(this).pixastic("desaturate");
    Pixastic.revert(this);
},

mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).pixastic("desaturate");
}
}, '.imageStyle');
```

Comment: Thank's.. But now i seem to have an issue with $(this) inside the each function. it's certainly not triggering the function on all other elements of the class. Could this still be referring to the hovered element even once inside the each function..?

Comment: the timing of pixtastic proccessing causes issues with this. I have ended up doing it a little round the houses but it works great. PS, the reason for the necessity of this, was because if the mouse entered and left the element to quickly the mouseleave was not triggered, so i am not triggering mouseleave on all stranded elements, on mouseenter. i have updated my post.

Comment: But thank you for correctly answering my original query, so i have accepted, your answer.